# how to ajax a table output from SQL database

Tags: php, ajax, database

first post ever here and kind of a green horn when it comes to programming. so heres the problem, i made a search module that filters emails based on a dropdown list. i did it, worked fine but i want to AJAX the output rather than a simple html table output. problem is i dont have a clue how to convert my code into ajax and or what to put in my JS, any advice could help.

```
if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<div class = "container-fluid">';
    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">';
    echo "<tr><th>from_email</th><th>email</th><th>date_added</th></tr>"; 
      while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "<tr><td>"; 
      echo $row['from_email'];
      echo "</td><td>";   
      echo $row['email'];
      echo "</td><td>";    
      echo $row['date_added'];
      echo "</td></tr>";
      }
      echo '</table>';
      echo '</div>';
}   else{
    echo '<div class = "container-fluid">';
    echo "There is no such search Results";
    echo '</div>';
}
```

so thats how i echo my current output in my html file

```
if ( $_POST['Type'] == 'domain' && !empty($_POST["search"])) {
    $sql="SELECT email, date_added, from_email FROM mailer_dne WHERE from_email LIKE '%".$search_value."%'";
    $res=$con->query($sql);
}
elseif ( $_POST["Type"] == 'email' && !empty($_POST["search"])) {
    $sql="SELECT email, date_added, from_email FROM mailer_dne WHERE from_email LIKE '$search_value'";
    $res=$con->query($sql);
}
```

and this is how i filter the search. any advice on how to ajax this?

Comment: The most easy example would be the use of jQuery, which is a javascript library. You can even find hundreads of thousands of examples/tutorials. Also please research XSS, SQL inject vulnerabilities. You are prone to hacking the way your code is written.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670979/mysql-php-js-live-search

Comment: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-ajax-live-search.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603188/searching-mysql-database-with-php-ajax-and-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching MySQL database with PHP, AJAX and jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603188/searching-mysql-database-with-php-ajax-and-jquery)